# Please give a specific example of a monoid with such properties below:

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a monoid. For some $c \in G$ with $c^2 = c$, does it imply $c = e$ where $e$ is the identity?

If $G$ is a group, it is trivial. What if $G$ is a monoid but not a group?

Examples are needed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The hint is always in the assumptions: you note yourself it is trivial when $G$ is a group. So can you think of a $G$ which is a monoid and not a group, and in particular one without inverses? What about $2 \times 2$ real matrices under multiplication? And what about the element
$$
c = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} ?
$$

Comment: Thanks for your analysis!

Comment: I will try to construct more common examples of monoid and semi-groups with particular properties!